# About hash functions

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

Let's consider a bidimensionnal array, declared as follow:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool array[N1][N2];
```

I have to know whether each line of this array have exactly one `true` value at the same position.

For example the following is ok:

```
{ 
  { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
  { 0, 0, 1, 1 }
}
```

Whereas this is incorrect:

```
{ 
  { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 1, 1 }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
static uintmax_t hash(const bool *t, size_t n) 
{
    uintmax_t retv = 0U;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (t[i] == true)
            retv |= 1 << i;
    return retv;
}

static int is_valid(bool n) 
{ 
    return n != 0 && (n & (n - 1)) == 0;
}

bool check(bool t[N1][N2])
{
    uintmax_t thash[N1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
        thash[i] = hash(t[i], N2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N1; ++j)
            if (i != j && !is_valid(thash[i] & thash[j]))
                return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

But it works only with `N1 <= sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT`. Do you know a best way to solve it?

Comment: Oups, I think I did not explain my problem very well. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create another array that's the size of N2 (number of columns), set it to all `true`, then `and` each column in each row with that. In the end, check to see if your new array has exactly one set bit.

```
bool array[N1][N2];  // this is initialized somehow
bool result[N2];
int i, j;

// initialize result array
for (j = 0; j < N2; ++j)
{
    result[j] = 1;
}

// Now go through the array, computing the result
for (i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N2; ++j)
    {
        result[j] &= array[i][j];
    }
}

// At this point, you can check the result array.
// If your array is valid, then result should have only one '1' in it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pack the bits into an integer. Instead, go over each two adjacent lines `i` and `i+1` and sum `!(a[i][j] ^ a[i+1][j])` (the NOT of the XOR of bits in the two lines). The sum has to be exactly 1 for each line.

Note I'm using the logical `not` and not the bitwise `not`. I don't want to get -1s (which is the bitwise not of 0).

Comment: This is not correct, if the lines are identical (with zero or more `true`) the sum will be zero.